# Cannot resolve "framework" in simple JOGL example

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

I am trying to run the JOGL java example called "GL4 Hello Triangle", which can be found at
https://github.com/java-opengl-labs/helloTriangle

I copied the code to an eclipse file, and I have linked to jogl, and I can import all the com.jogamp.opengl.... However, when I try to import

```
import framework.BufferUtils;
import framework.GlDebugOutput;
import framework.Semantic;
```

I get the error 
"The import framework cannot be resolved"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure, you are trying to import from the correct packages?

Comment: Those classes are here: https://github.com/java-opengl-labs/helloTriangle/tree/master/HelloTriangle/src/framework They are parts of @elect 's framework, they don't belong to JOGL itself. JogAmp JOGL != java-opengl-labs. You can contact the author of this framework: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1047713/elect

Comment: His project is packaged as a Netbeans project, you have to add the classes above into the source files of the Eclipse project.